# Manipulating hover state

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to manipulate :hover state through HTML DOM like:

```
javascript:void("document.body.backgroundColor=red");
```

In the above code or through html DOM can hover state be defined but not through css.
I want to make the background color red on only hover state so how can i solve this when the above code is placed in the URL?

Comment: why don't you just use css?

Comment: @yentup that was a joke .How can i use css in url

Comment: jQuery hover no good to you?

Comment: He wants to set the background of `<body>`, not the link.

Comment: @BenM yes that's what i needed and not through jquery and css through dom

Comment: Why? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery includes the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function:

```
$('#myDiv').hover(function() {  
    $('body').css('backgroundColor', '#ff0000');
}, function() {  
    $('body').css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
});
```

Comment: It does, but there's no indication jQuery is an option.

Comment: When I answered, this was tagged as jQuery too.

Comment: @BenM u are not being attentive to my post.My problem is on the url of the browser sir

Comment: @user2060755 why and how would you ever put styling in a url??

Comment: @yentup i wanted to know can hover state be handled through DOM if so than it could be a big treasure for me

Comment: `hover` is an event, not a DOM element. Do you mean how it can be achieved through JavaScript?

Comment: @user2060755 bind anonymous functions to the `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` events that manipulate the DOM. Quite why you'd want to do that entirely through the address bar though, is beyond me. As @Anthony Grist has said, this is **VERY** bad practice.

Comment: @BenM no it cannot be a bad practice as i heard it could be done through url too so i asked

Comment: @BenM I wanted to change color when mouse hovers on the document through URL not through plain javascript nither through jquery and css that is not a part of my problem sir

Comment: Just because something's possible doesn't mean it should be done. The existence of `eval()` is a case-in-point.

Comment: @BenM help me sir.There is ofcourse a logic behind this

Comment: I told you what you need to do above.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

JS:

```
function changeBGC(color){
    document.bgColor = color;
}
```

A attribute:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="javascript:changeBGC('#000000')">Some link</a>
```

Comment: that was never my problem .I wanted to change color when mouse hovers on the document through URL not through plain javascript

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use jQuery's hover or mouseOver functions? Why the need to set it through URL?

Comment: Only reason I could see for using the URL input to manipulate the DOM is if you're trying to change code that's not hosted by you. Meaning a site that's not your own.

Comment: omg how did u know that, dont call fbi.Just kidding